# How to query the event repository in a microservice Event Sourcing architecture with Spring Cloud Stream Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, microservices, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

**CLARIFICATION**: Notice that this question is different form this one: [How to implement a microservice Event Driven architecture with Spring Cloud Stream Kafka and Database per service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140285/how-to-implement-a-microservice-event-driven-architecture-with-spring-cloud-stre)

This one is about using [Kafka as the only repository (of events)](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html), no DB needed, The other one is about using a [Database (MariaDB) per service + Kafka](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html).

I would like to implement an Event Sourcing architecture to handle distributed transactions:

```
OrdersService <------------> | Kafka Event Store | <------------>PaymentsService
                subscribe/                           subscribe/
                   find                                 find
```

OrdersService receives an order request and stores the new Order in the broker.

```
private OrderBusiness orderBusiness;    

@PostMapping
public Order createOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
    logger.debug("createOrder()");
    //do whatever
    //Publish the new Order with state = pending
    order.setState(PENDING);
    try{       
       orderSource.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(order).build());
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("{}", e);
    }
    return order;
}
```

This is my main doubt: how can I query a Kafka broker? Imagine I want to search for orders by user/date,state, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a microservice Event Driven architecture with Spring Cloud Stream Kafka and Database per service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140285/how-to-implement-a-microservice-event-driven-architecture-with-spring-cloud-stre)

Comment: Hi Spencer, I don't think it's a duplicate. The other one is about using Database (MariaDB) per service + Kafka. This one is about using Kafka as the only repository (of events), no DB needed: http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html vs http://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** you cannot query the broker but you could exploit Kafka's Streams API and "Interactive Queries".

**Long answer:** The access pattern for reading Kafka topics, are linear scans and not random lookups. Of course, you can also reposition at any time via `#seek()`, but only by *offset* or *time*. Also topics are sharded into partitions and data is (by default) hash partitioned by key (data model is key-value pairs). So there is a notion of a key.

However, you can use Kafka's [Streams API](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams) that allows you to build an app that hold the current state -- base on a Kafka topics that is the ground truth -- as a materialized view (basically a cache). ["Interactive Queries"](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#interactive-queries) allows you to query this materialized view.

For more details, see this two blog post:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-dichotomy-rethinking-the-way-we-treat-data-and-services/

Comment: To add to Matthias' point above, we will have direct support for KStream in upcoming versions of Spring Kafka and Spring Cloud Stream.

Comment: Great! Thank you both for the info!